# Multiple field updates in flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a flow with a scheduled path.  When that time is reached, I want to update multiple fields.  I have created one Update Record element for each field update, and have chained them together.  My question is, will the object trigger run after each field update, or when all the field updates have been made in the flow?

Answer (score 1):

Each Update Records element will initiate the save sequence defined in [Triggers and Order Of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)

A better strategy is to use Assignment element(s) and assign to a record variable and then use a single Update Records element

[Note that each SOQL/DML element (as well as Apex Action) are bulkified](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_bulkification.htm&type=5) - all flow interviews that start in a transaction will run in "parallel" and when they all hit the same DML element, the Flow runtime engine bulkifies the SOQL/DML/Apex action so triggers execute efficiently.